# VS2010 _DELETE_CRT macro in STL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How do I turn off "support for debug heap" in VS2010's STL implementation? I wrote a memory tracker which overloads new and delete and adds a tracking node in front of allocations. Sadly some STL objects use my operator new and then try to delete with the below macro instead of my operator delete. That means they try to `free` an address that wasn't returned by `malloc`. Because of the below macros my code crashes in debug but not in release (hah).

From `<xdebug>`:

```
// SUPPORT FOR DEBUG HEAP
#if defined(_DEBUG)
     #define _DELETE_CRT(ptr) _STD _DebugHeapDelete(ptr)

    template<class _Ty>
    void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL _DebugHeapDelete(_Ty *_Ptr)
    {   //  delete from the debug CRT heap even if operator delete exists
    if (_Ptr != 0)
        {   // worth deleting
        _Ptr->~_Ty();
        // delete as _NORMAL_BLOCK, not _CRT_BLOCK, since we might have
        // facets allocated by normal new.
        free(_Ptr);
        }
    }

#else /* defined(_DEBUG) */
    #define _DELETE_CRT(ptr)        delete (ptr)
```

For reference, the exact crash is in `locale operator=`:

```
locale& operator=(const locale& _Right) _THROW0()
    {   // assign a locale
if (_Ptr != _Right._Ptr)
    {   // different implementation, point at new one
    _DELETE_CRT(_Ptr->_Decref());
    _Ptr = _Right._Ptr;
    _Ptr->_Incref();
    }
return (*this);
}
```

I don't even see what `_DebugHeapDelete` is buying them - it looks identical to what `operator delete` would do in any configuration.

Comment: You could easily answer yourself what it buys them if you stepped through a `delete` call in debug and release mode. In debug, ultimately a call to `_free_dbg_nolock` will be made that checks certain things on the to-be-deleted pointer (and the heap). In release mode, `operator delete` will just call `free`. I don't know what exactly they check and why they do it, but that's not our business now, is it? I like that debug heap.

Comment: @Xeo But you get the benefits of the debug heap whether you use `_DebugHeapDelete` or `delete`. `_DebugHeapDelete` is exactly `delete` except it bypasses `operator delete` and calls `free` directly instead. That means it bypasses the user's `operator delete` (even when it was allocated with the user's `operator new`, which seems like a bug to me). What's the point of *that*?

Answer (score 1):

Set `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` in your environment.

(That's an environment variable, not a `#define`, by the way)

Comment: This does disable the debug heap, but it doesn't stop STL from calling `_DebugHeapDelete` instead of `operator delete` in debug. My problem is slightly different then just disabling the debug heap - but I don't know why VS has STL setup with these new/delete macros in the first place.